# React Native Exportiing

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am getting the following error when I am trying to build my React Native bundle.

Syntax Error components/Example/index.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:20)

I am not sure if it's a problem with my eslint/babel configs. Here are the files.

components/Example/index.js

```
export default from './View'
```

components/Example/View.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes, Button } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { updateExampleData } from '../../actions/example'

class Example extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    exampleProp: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  const incrementData = () => {
    const newIncrement = this.props.exampleProp + 1
    updateExampleData(newIncrement)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>exampleData: {this.props.exampleProp} </Text>
          <Button
            onPress={incrementData}
            title="Increment Data"
            color="#841584"
          />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    const exampleProp = state.example.example
    const newProps = {
      exampleProp: exampleProp
    }
    return newProps
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Example)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "SportsApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint": "^4.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "jest-expo": "~19.0.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-orientation-listener": "0.0.4",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-tableview-simple": "^0.16.8",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^19.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.46.1"
  }
}
```

eslint.json

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

I have written react-redux before but I did not do the parsing configurations for that project so I am wondering if the syntax error has something to do with that. I am pretty sure my index.js files for the components were written with the same syntax as that in the provided file where the syntax error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
export { default } from './View'
```

In your index.js

Comment: Actually I think it is exporting the class not the connect function which binds the component to redux. That is not good

Comment: I believe what you were trying to use is a proposal in stage 1 (https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from). You can try using this preset: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-native-stage-0

Comment: @JackFrye it's not exporting the class.

Comment: You are right. I tried exporting the connect with a constant and got the same error. That is not the issue. Thanks

Comment: when I am importing the component, its type is undefined

Comment: I think that is right. Do you have any docs on how react-native interacts with redux, babel, and eslint as far as export syntax? All these different js libraries and syntaxes can be a little confusing and I'd like to get them all straight.

Comment: This has nothing to do with React Native. This is just JavaScript. See this example: https://codepen.io/sscaff1/project/editor/XmyEkk. You can read more on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export